# How to generate Delegates and Controllers for Spring OpenApi generator 6.6.0

Tags: java, spring, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using [Spring OpenApi generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring/) for my Spring Boot web app. Everything worked fine for version 6.0.0, but now I want to update it to the latest version (6.6.0). My gradle task looks like this:

```
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "spring"
    inputSpec = "$projectDir/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml"
    outputDir = "$buildDir/generated"
    apiPackage = "com.myapp.web.api.controller"
    invokerPackage = "com.myapp.web.api.invoker"
    modelPackage = "com.myapp.web.api.model"
    modelNamePrefix = "Dto"
    configOptions = [
            openApiNullable: "false",
            useSwaggerUI: "false",
            delegatePattern: "true",
            useTags: "true",
            implicitHeaders: "true",
            additionalModelTypeAnnotations: "@lombok.AllArgsConstructor;@lombok.NoArgsConstructor;@lombok.Builder(toBuilder = true)",
            performBeanValidation: "true",
            generatedConstructorWithRequiredArgs: "false"
    ]
}
```

Everything was fine for the previous version of the generator, but with 6.6.0 it throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map {CONTROLLER} method`.

I assume it is because it generates controllers with "RequestMapping" annotation

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("${openapi.myapp.base-path:}")
public class StuffApiController implements StuffApi {
```

Is it possible to prevent it from adding RequestMapping on the Controller class somehow? Or what is the correct configuration to generate all three of Api, Controller and Delegate correctly?

Comment: FYI. [OpenAPI Generator v7.0.0](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/releases/tag/v7.0.0) has been released. Please give it a try to see it works better for your use cases.